# How much consistency should I keep throughout writing (document) and presentating (slides)?

Tags: design-principles, information-graphics, critique, information-design

I have a scientific document and I'm about to presentate it. Many instructions and guildlines help me to make a perfect document or a presentation, but I want to go further: make a perfect presentation with both of them. My question is do you need to keep the consistency between them? Which one you will keep and which one not?

Here is the cover and the first page of my document:
[image]

Choice 1: Keep its structure and font color:
[image]

Choice 2: Change its structure but keep the font color:
[image]

Choice 3: Change everything:
[image]

I haven't tried to change the font, but I think this font (bold Arial) is OK. Because this is a scientific paper, the title must keep every information, I can't shorten it anymore.

Also, because many people ask me if I need to follow some scienctific guildline, I will say that I am free to create my style, as long as it keeps the contain as a scientific paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to keep the paper and slides linked (e.g., you'll be handing the paper out as part of the presentation, readers will have to sort through various slide shows to find yours, etc.) you should keep as many of the graphic elements consistent as possible.

Examples 1 and 2 both keep most of the graphic elements the same; people expect some change since you're going from a portrait (Letter or A4 for the paper) layout to a landscape one (PowerPoint / Keynote for the presentation). Personally, I like the second example as it keeps the graphic elements together but also gives a visual cue as to where the title is on the title slide. Humans are pretty good at non-visual cues, so if there's a line at the top of a paper in a larger font our brains are pretty good at saying "that's the title" but it's sometimes a little trickier on a PowerPoint slide.

That being said, the Design Police aren't going to kick in your door and drag you away to Design Prison (where you're forced to mine for pixels all day) if you go with two different graphic layouts for your presentation and paper. Think of it as branding - if this were a sandwich and drink, would it be confusing for you to open the box and see two different graphic styles on the sandwich and drink in the same box?

Comment: I don't get your metaphor about the police and the prison. If the sandwich and the drink in the same box is confusing, then why does the police not drag me into the prison?

Comment: Do you recommend me to use the second choice?

Comment: There's no such thing as the Design Police. If there were, there would be far fewer Comic Sans users. It's hyperbole.

Comment: I like it. I also like cream cheese and jelly on a sandwich, but there are many who might not. You originally asked for some guidelines, and I believe that the second example you gave did a nice job of using the same design elements in two different areas without directly copying it.

Comment: I know the police is a hyperbole. I just can't see how it goes with the sandwich. About the choices, I will choose the second one as you suggested. Also, in a default theme, a lighter blue is used and I see it's also nice. I think that use the lighter one makes the slides bright without breaking the consistency. What do you think?